# How to find the git branch I was accidentally committing to after switching back to master

Tags: git

I was working on a git branch other than master. I don't remember its name. When I was done with it, I did

```
git add .
git commit -am "foo"
```

I didn't push the commits.

I switched to master `git co master`. I don't know how to get back to my branch and commit the changes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing `git branch` will list all your local branches. Then you can check out the branch you want:

```
git branch
git checkout branch-name
```

---

Once you have everything committed correctly on the branch, you can merge it back to master:

```
# while on your feature branch
git commit -m "Finishing my feature"
git checkout master
git merge branch-name
git push origin master
```

Note that **you aren't pushing from your feature branch**, but rather merging your feature branch to `master` and then pushing `master`. Feature branches typically aren't tracking a remote repository, so there's nowhere for them to push to.

Comment: I did checked my branches with `git branch`, and I think I found the branch I was working on, but when I switched to his one, there was nothing to commit... As if every thing I had done had been erased.

Comment: There won't be anything to commit because you already committed it before you switched off of the branch. You should, however, be able to check out your branch and `git log` or `git diff master` to see whether you successfully committed the changes on the branch.

Comment: I found the right branch. I checked with `git diff master` and it differs a lot. Can you tell me the exact command to merge this branch to master? I don't want to mess it up.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought I had lost all my unpushed work.

Answer (score 2):

If you run `git log -g` you should see a message something like:

```
commit <commit-id>
Reflog: HEAD@{0} (My Name <me@somehwere>)
Reflog message: checkout: moving from forgot-this-branch to master
```

This will tell you the name of the branch that you most recently moved off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reflog to show where you've been:

```
git reflog show HEAD
```

This will give the history of HEAD and will show something like:

```
9c4d528 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from tooling to master
```

along with earlier changes affecting HEAD

Answer (score 0):

Use `git branch` to list all of your branches. That will hopefully jog your memory :-)

The branch should definitely appear in that list unless you used `git branch -d` (or `git branch -D`) to remove the branch.

Then use `git checkout` to switch back to that branch, as you normally would.

---

You implied you might have some uncommitted changes on `master` that you want to commit on your other branch. If that's the case, `git checkout` won't work with a dirty working tree. In that case, use `git stash save` to save your changes to a temporary change stack, `git checkout` to switch branches, and then `git stash pop` to get rid of the stash and get the changes back into the working tree. Then you can use `git commit` as normal.

Comment: The problem is I don't know what branch I was working on, even after checking with `git branch`... I think I know, but when I switched to that branch, it said there was nothing to commit.

Comment: Yes, because you were working in the `master` branch. Did you commit on `master` or were the files still only in an edited (uncommitted, un-added to the index) state?

Comment: Here is exactly what I did : I was working on postgres-setup. When I was done, I did : `git add .`, `git commit -am "done with PostgreSQL setup"`, `git co master`, `git push`.

Comment: You need to use `git merge` to merge your changes from your other branch to `master` before they can be pushed from `master` to your remote branch. (`git merge other_branch` before `git push`) It is also possible that you need to do the reverse (`git checkout other_branch`, `git merge master`) if both branches have diverged.